# Discord JDA - embed Button reaction

Tags: java, discord

i want to put a embed in a specific channel. When you click on "login", a log from that should be send into a channel like "login-log". So when you click on login, a administrator can see in a channel: the user abdscasd logged in at 6:oo or something like that.
(sorry for bad english)

I already craeted a embed and two buttons. But i dont know how to create the button interact event

How can i tell him to do that? I'm new to this.

Thank you!

```
package main;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.EmbedBuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.Permission;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.interaction.component.ButtonInteractionEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.MessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.interactions.components.buttons.Button;

public class stempelsystem extends ListenerAdapter {

    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent ereignis) {

        if (ereignis.getMessage().getContentStripped().equals("!hochfahren")) {
            if (ereignis.getMember().getPermissions().contains(Permission.ADMINISTRATOR)) {
                EmbedBuilder embed = new EmbedBuilder();
                embed.setTitle("Timestamp");
                embed.setThumbnail("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1053705072682471525/1054037899429036123/Download.png");
                embed.setColor(0x42b580);
                embed.setDescription("");
                embed.addField(":question: Warum muss ich mich ein- bzw. ausstempeln?", "Dies dient zur Zeiterfassung um die Aktivität zu überprüfen, auch für mögliche Beförderungen.", true);
                embed.addField(":question: Was passiert wenn ich mich vergesse einzuloggen?","Unter umständen kann dies eine Beförderung beeinträchtigen oder zu einer Kündigung führen.",true);

                Button button = Button.success("login", "Login");
                Button button2 = Button.danger("logout", "Melde dich hier ab!");

                ereignis.getChannel().sendMessageEmbeds(embed.build()).setActionRow(button, button2).queue();


            }



        }
    }
//???????????????????????? i dont know
    public void onButtonInteractionEvent (ButtonInteractionEvent ereignis){
        if (ereignis.getButton().getId().equals("login")){





        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe reading the [official wiki](https://jda.wiki/using-jda/interactions/#component-interactions) might help

Answer (score 0):

So if i've understood correctly, it should look like this:

```
@Override
public void onButtonInteractionEvent (ButtonInteractionEvent ereignis){
    if (ereignis.getComponentId() == "login"){
        // login method
        
    }

    if (ereignis.getComponentId() == "logout") {
        // logout method

    }

}
```

(don't forget to register your class listener on jda start)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).